# All browsers crashing after upgrade

Tags: 11.10, browser

After system update yesterday, all browsers on Ubuntu 11.10 seem to be crashing. The system is almost unusable because browsers have been essential these days. There is no way to use any browser for more than 2 minutes.  I tried the steps mentioned in a related issue like 
reinstalling nvidia-drivers and libvdpau1 but those did not help.
I am um unable to see any open bugs too.

Comment: Launch it in a terminal and give us the output (by editing this post), we can't help otherwise.

Comment: Open terminal, type `google-chrome` and paste here log from terminal (last few lines of error). Maybe that show where is error.

Comment: Not just Ubuntu either. Also happening on Arch after kernel update yesterday. Booting older kernel improves matters, but still buggy where flash is involved. Looks like a bad kernel issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's something in the kernel.  booting into -17 rather than the new -18 solves the problem (i had the same issue)...

This is after a kernel upgrade which happened yesterday. The following Launchpad bug tracks that

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/972821

And here the patch for solving the issue.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/972821/comments/10

The patched kernel solved the problem for me. I think, the next kernel upgrade should resolve it.

Comment: Let me try that, because it was indeed a kernel upgrade that happened yesterday.

Comment: How to boot to old kernel?

Comment: On Ubuntu this patch solved the problem - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/972821/comments/10

Answer (score 1):

Been having the problem with 11.10. Even after all updates for 11.10. Both Chromium and Firefox had similar symptoms. Flash applets would not run. Youtube would not play. But if you shut flash off in firefox, then some videos would play, and others wouldn't. I even tried the firefox add-on called flash aid. Very easy to use, but still didn't fix it.

Now get this, if you [install Google Chrome, stable version for Ubuntu](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/10/install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-11-10-11-04-10-10-10-04/) (or just [go here](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/)), it works great on youtube and flash. Then if you run flash aid in firefox, it will let you select "Google from chrome" as one of the possible flash options. Select it. Also select the rest of the defaults. It will have flash working great in Firefox and Chromium too with version 11.2.202.236.