# How to downgrade kernel image?

Tags: kernel, downgrade

Recently I updated my linux kernel from 3.0.0-17 to 3.0.0-18. And now chromium keeps giving me a segmentation fault and so does ubuntu-bug and even nautilus. Now I want to downgrade back to 3.0.0-17 until the bug is fixed. So how do I do that?

I run ubuntu11.10 32-bit.

Comment: My problem's been resolved by upgrading to 3.0.0-19.

Answer (score 1):

If you recently installed a new kernel your old kernel should still be installed as well.  You should be able to interrupt the boot and select a previous kernel from the bootloader menu; for grub (the default bootloader on standard PC systems) hold `SHIFT` as the BIOS finishes and then select `Previous Kernels` and pick a known good kernel from there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that its due to kernel upgrade ? If you are sure, follow this [How to downgrade the Kernel on 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71139/how-to-downgrade-the-kernel-on-11-10) . Check this thread as well [All browsers crashing after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119407/ubuntu-11-10-all-browsers-crashing-after-upgrade-since-yesterday)

Comment: I've already tried that, it didn't work so I asked this question. I'm quite sure it's because of the kernel upgrade. I found the bug on launchpad:https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/972821

Comment: For those interested, a new kernel that fixes that bug has now been released.